# What is the best practise for updating a collection of items (ie: in a data grid) when refreshing details from a web service?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

This seems to be a problem that I encounter regularly: I have a list control, in this case a DataGrid, and the items in the control come from a web service. My application regularly asks the web service for the latest list of items. Compared with what my application currently has, the resulting list may have additional items, fewer items, or different details for existing items.

How do I update my control (ie: my data grid) without:

1) De-selecting the user's currently selected items.
2) Resetting the ordering that the user may have set on various columns.
3) Doing anything else that makes it jarring for the user.
4) Incorporating too much code, turning it into an unmaintainable mess.

Am I simply going about this whole thing wrong? It seems to me this scenario should be simple to address with something as versatile as WPF.

My current thinking is to use INotifyPropertyChanged on each item, and an ObservableCollection. Then, for each item in the list, update every property when we do the refresh (adding and removing items from the collection as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, use ObservableCollection

1) De-selecting the user's currently selected items.

You can use either `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(rootElem.DataContext).Current` or create a `SelectedItem` property, and bind it to the UI element. I prefer `SelectedItem` because it is less view related. For deselecting just set it to null.

2) Resetting the ordering that the user may have set on various columns.
You can easily swap two elements in `ObservableCollection`, and  that change immediately will appear in the view.

```
var tmp = myObsCollection[i];
myObsCollection[i] = myObsCollection[j];
myObsCollection[j] = tmp;
```

Also you can use keep order property in your items, configure sorting in CollectionView, and just rearrange orders when needed and call view.Refresh();

3) You don't need to update all properties for updated items, just find the correct item index and replace it with new one, WPF will update automatically

```
myObsCollection[fIndex] = updatedItem;
```

Use the same logic for delete/add elements

Comment: I feel this solution has too much code and wiring, and is therefore not an alternative to my current thinking.

Comment: describe your current thinking in question pls, because it is not clear from the question